# Почему hibernate не видит внешний ключ?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

Есть 2 сущности:

```
@Entity
public class MyMainEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String role;
    private String password;
    private String login;
    private String mail;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity")
    List<Tovar> tovars = null;
} 
@Entity
public class Tovar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String img;
    private String amount;
    private String price;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
    MyMainEntity entity = null;
}
```

При заполнении,изменении проблем нет.Но когда я пытаюсь получить весь список товаров в которых внешний ключ показывает на `id` `MyMainEntity.class` получаю ошибку что внешнего ключа нет несмотря на то что он есть.Помогите пжлста....
Код получения :

```
public String get(MyMainEntity myMainEntity){
        Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Tovar.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("entity_id",myMainEntity.getId()));
        criteria.setMaxResults(200);
        List l = criteria.list();
        System.out.println(l.toString());
        return l.toString();
    }
```

И StackTrace :

```
Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: entity_id of: com.springapp.mvc.models.Tovar
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: entity_id of: com.springapp.mvc.models.Tovar
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1995)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:61)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1970)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:518)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:534)
    org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.toSqlString(SimpleExpression.java:82)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:417)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:123)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:92)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:97)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1663)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    com.springapp.mvc.service.MyServiceClass.get(MyServiceClass.java:48)
    com.springapp.mvc.service.MyServiceClass$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6125fa23.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    com.springapp.mvc.service.MyServiceClass$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54280edd.get(<generated>)
    com.springapp.mvc.HelloController.ban_panel4(HelloController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: Фактически в бд, в таблице Tovar, создаётся поле entity_id, заполняется значениями?

Comment: @Bakhuss да....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Entity
public class Tovar {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
    MyMainEntity entity = null;
}
```

Comment: теперь другая ошибка.                  На месте где criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("entity_id",myMainEntity.getId()));  ругается на myMainEntity.getId();

Comment: Exception вот такой : PropertyAccessException  : could not get a field value by reflection getter of  package.MyMainEntity.id

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 может нужно добавить метод `public Integer getId()` в `MyMainEntity`?

Comment: все геттеры/сеттеры есть.

Comment: Если беру на какую то переменную берётся.и когда я эту переменную вставляют вместо getId() происходит тоже самое.

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 видимо у тебя ошибка в запросе. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327906/org-hibernate-propertyaccessexception-could-not-get-a-field-value-by-reflection) похожая ошибка.

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 извиняюсь, я в начале дал не верный ответ. Я обновил ответ, попробуйте так. Если не выйдет, я удалю ответ.

Comment: Спасибо.первый вариант заработал.только выборку сделал по другому.Оказалось в Restriction запросах тоже надо вытаскивать объединённые данные.inner join и.т.п